# Could not build wheels for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed

Tags: python, pyaudio, python-wheel

I tried to install `pyaudio`, but it returns an error like this:

```
Could not build wheels for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
```

[image: picture of the terminal]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include the relevant text in your post - images are not useful for searching for content later and is hard to parse for those who uses a screen reader. You can install the wheel package by using `pip install wheel`.

Comment: The screenshot of the error isn't particularly readable even for people with normal vision.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you just need to install the `wheel` package.
You can do this by running `pip install wheel` at the terminal.

Comment: Can someone explain why this message appears since pip 20.1?

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8102

Answer (score 9):

Upgrading pip setuptools wheel did the trick for me.

`pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

This problem started appearing since I upgraded to pip 20. Here is some link i found useful [Could not build wheels](https://github.com/pydata/bottleneck/issues/281)