# HOW do i fix python ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio?

Tags: python, pyaudio, portaudio

1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not build wheels for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559359/could-not-build-wheels-for-pyaudio-since-package-wheel-is-not-installed)

Comment: thanks a lot but wheels are installed